# Why does Scala create a ~/tmp directory when I run a script?

Tags: scala, scripting

When I execute a Scala script from the command line, a directory named "tmp" is created in my home directory. It is always empty, so I simply deleted it without any apparent problem. Of course, when I run another Scala script, it reappears.

Is there a configuration file/flag by which I can change this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Scala probably compiles the script to byte code, and byte code files are stored temporarily under tmp directory. That would be my guess.

Comment: Juha-

Thanks for your answer. My hope is to prevent the directory creation from happening in my home directory ;) I would imagine it would default to /tmp rather than ~/tmp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Early versions of the Scala interpreter wrote generated class files out to disk, in a temporary directory.

Try a newer version.